# NullPointerException error on Android

Tags: android

I get a LOT of errors from LogCat when I try running my app on an emulator. After looking around I think my main error is a the NullPointerException error which I assume is coming from calling the array of usernames from source and comparing them with the username posted on the form.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Context context = getApplicationContext();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void hitSubmit(View button){
    final Spinner feedbackSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerFeedbackType);
    String feedbackType = feedbackSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(feedbackType.equals("Please Select")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a country.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    final EditText fnField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FN);
    String FN = fnField.getText().toString();
    if(FN.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your first name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    final EditText lnField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LN);
    String LN = lnField.getText().toString();
    if(LN.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your last name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    final EditText phoneField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PN);
    String PN = phoneField.getText().toString();
    if(PN.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your phone number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    final EditText Email1Field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EA);
    String EA1 = Email1Field.getText().toString();
    if(EA1.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an email address.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    final EditText Email2Field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EA2);
    String EA2 = Email2Field.getText().toString();
    if(!EA2.equals(EA1)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your email address' do not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    final EditText userField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.User);
    String user = userField.getText().toString();
    if(!user.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] usernameArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.usernames);
    int userint = usernameArray.length;
    for(int x=0;x<userint;x++){
        if(user.equals(usernameArray[x])){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Username already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
    RadioButton rb1, rb2;
    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    if(!rb1.isChecked() && !rb2.isChecked()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please select a gender.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    finish();

}

public void hitClear(View button){
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}

}
```

--the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Homework 1</string>
    <string name="FN">First Name</string>
    <string name="LN">Last Name</string>
    <string name="PN">Phone Number</string>
    <string name="EA">Email Address</string>
    <string name="REEA">Re-enter Email</string>
    <string name="User">Username</string>
    <string name="Pw">Password</string>
    <string name="Gender">Gender</string>
    <string name="Country">Country</string>
    <string name="action_settings">.</string>
    <string name="clear">Clear</string>
    <string name="submit">Submit</string>
    <string name="female">Female</string>
    <string name="male">Male</string>
    <string name="country_prompt">Choose a country</string>
    <string name="countrytype1">Malaysia</string>
    <string name="countrytype2">United States</string>
    <string name="countrytype3">Indonesia</string>
    <string name="countrytype4">France</string>
    <string name="countrytype5">Italy</string>
    <string name="countrytype6">Singapore</string>
    <string name="countrytype7">New Zealand</string>
    <string name="countrytype8">India</string>
    <string-array name="country_arrays">
        <item>Please Select</item>
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>Singapore</item>
        <item>New Zealand</item>
        <item>India</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="usernames">
        <item>Bryan</item>
        <item>John</item>
        <item>Matt</item>
        <item>Mike</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Thanks.

EDIT: Adding activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/FN"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:hint="@string/FN"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/LN"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:hint="@string/LN"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/PN"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:hint="@string/PN"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EA"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/EA"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EA2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:hint="@string/REEA"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/User"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:hint="@string/User"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Pw"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:hint="@string/Pw"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RadioGroup 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="53dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/female" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="@string/male" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Country"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/SpinnerFeedbackType"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:onClick="hitSubmit"         
            android:text="@string/clear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:onClick="hitClear"         
            android:text="@string/submit" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you provide a stack trace and gives the line causing it?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with LogCat but it doesn't give me lines where the error occurs (unless I'm missing something), it says PID and TID are 870, and the error message says "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/come.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @WillNasby usually there is a line which tells you which line of MainActivity is causing the crash. Just post all the red bits in your logcat so we can help you.

Comment: Also, I'd like to see you activity_main file if you don't mind. And just to pick at some English if you don't mind, where you say address' that should be addresses. address' implies possessiveness.

Comment: Im a bit suspicious on the manifest file. Hope you have declared the activity in the manifest file. In this path com.example.myapplication/come.example.myapplication.MainActivity, one says com and another says come. and the package name is com.example.myapplication. where is "come.example.myapplication" (Note the extra 'e')

Comment: The "Context context = getApplicationContext();" line was causing the problems. I had it in there before when I was doing something a different way. The username field and gender radio buttons are still causing issues, but I'm going to look into that before posting again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use *Context context = getApplicationContext();* in first line of your activity. it's wrong. If you need get context, you could use itself.

Just use **this** or **this.getBaseContext()**

Also, if you checked the error message it shown you special line where occurs error. ex. *at com.example.test.MyActivity.(MyActivity.java:**47**)* shows line 47

Answer (score 0):

1st of all why you need getapplication() context in activity, if you can use **"this" or MainActivity.class** .If want to use **Context context = getApplicationContext();**  then put it in Oncreate() because it may contain the null value and can cause null point exception wherever used.**But keep in mind which/how/where context to be used**. Context object depends on where it came from originally.

Below is a table of the common places an application will receive a Context, and in each case what it is useful for:  [image: **which/how/where**].

For details about context check out[What is context](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/)

Answer (score 0):

Joining to all comments, you can also move the line

```
context = getApplicationContext();
```

to the onCreate method
i.e.

```
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = getApplicationContext();
}
```